# Making searches look like html pages with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my urls that currently look like,

http://www.mydomain.com/search.php?q=blue+widgets

too look like this,

http://www.mydomain.com/blue+widgets.html

The code below makes the urls look like this,

http://www.mydomain.com/blue+widgets/

How can I get it to add .html at the end? I tried several things and haven't been able to get it to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/(.*) search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`([^.]+)` is the frist group and means anything not a dot
`.html` is the left over to match the extension you want

Since you're using this on `.htaccess` you don't need the `/?`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the html to the pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)\.html$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```